# Does Videopad support alpha channels / transparency in videos?

Tags: video, video-editor, alpha

I use software from NCH called Videopad for all my video editing. I am trying to combine two video clips. The first is a standard MP4 video clip, but I have a second WEBM video file, encoded with the VP9 codec, which uses an alpha channel. That second clip is a short stinger that effectively does a stylistic wipe transition, and starts out with a transparent background. However, when I import it into Videopad, onto Video Track 2, it renders the transparent background as solid black, meaning I can't cleanly overlay it.

I am wondering if anyone else here has used Videopad before, and if you know of any way to force it to respect the alpha channel within an imported video.